# pull out data from json

Tags: php, json

I have a small piece of code that I am trying to write.  I am trying to pull data from a json array and with my little knowledge of this particular coding I am having issue.  Any direction or help would be appreciated.  Thanks

The last line show the link that when loaded in a browser returns a correct route listing with no errors.

```
   <?php
   function getroute($slat,$slong,$elat,$elong)
   {
   $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?               origin='.trim($slat).','.trim($slong).'&destination='.trim($elat).','.trim($elong).'&sensor=false&mode=driving';
   $json = @file_get_contents($url);
   $data=json_decode($json);
   $status = $data->status;
   if($status=="OK")
   return $data->routes->legs->distance->text;
   else
   return false;
   }


   //start
   $slat = '36.019432';
   $slong = '-84.227957';

   //end
   $elat = '36.0350416';
   $elong = '-84.0199746';


   $address = getroute($slat,$slong,$elat,$elong);
   if($address) {echo $address;} else {echo "Not found";}

   echo "
   <br>
   sLat: $slat<br>
   sLong: $slong<br>
   eLat: $elat<br>
   eLong: $elong<br>";

   echo 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?       origin='.trim($slat).','.trim($slong).'&destination='.trim($elat).','.trim($elong).'&sensor=false&mode=driving';
   ?>
```

I have also tried:

```
return $data->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;
```

and

```
return $data->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance[0]->text;
```

Comment: `$data->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text;` works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to loop through all arrays.

```
$data->routes
```

is an array

```
$data->routes[0]->legs
```

is also an array

So, you need to extract what you want to be returned.